# Installing packages from private pypi fails if password contains '@' character

Tags: python, pip, nexus, pypi

Installing packages from private pypi fails if password contains '@' character

So if I have
login: someLogin
password: Password@

then my pip.conf looks like:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://someLogin:Password@@nexus.privatepypy.com/repository/pypi/xxx
```

And this actually does not work. I have to type my password all the time.

Is there any workaround for this?

PS: Changing password is not a solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to percent scape it, as it is a URL.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>>> quote_plus('Password@')
'Password%40'
```

For example in Mongo, to connect you can use:

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#percent-escaping-username-and-password

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> username = urllib.parse.quote_plus('user')
>>> username
'user'
>>> password = urllib.parse.quote_plus('pass/word')
>>> password
'pass%2Fword'
>>> MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@127.0.0.1' % (username, password))
```

--- EDIT ---

I followed the code in pip to here:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1ea3f89ff9f005c78413907b36e55b3e76092612/src/pip/_internal/download.py#L140

And run the code manually, with both quoting and unquoting the password:

Unquoted:

```
>>> from urllib import parse as urllib_parse
>>> url = 'https://someLogin:Password@@nexus.privatepypy.com/repository/pypi/xxx'

>>> parsed = urllib_parse.urlparse(url)
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='someLogin:Password@@nexus.privatepypy.com', path='/repository/pypi/xxx', params='', query='', fragment='')

>>> netloc = parsed.netloc.rsplit("@", 1)[-1]
>>> netloc
'nexus.privatepypy.com'

>>> url = urllib_parse.urlunparse(parsed[:1] + (netloc,) + parsed[2:])
>>> url
'https://nexus.privatepypy.com/repository/pypi/xxx'

>>> def parse_credentials(netloc):
...    if "@" in netloc:
...        userinfo = netloc.rsplit("@", 1)[0]
...        if ":" in userinfo:
...            user, pwd = userinfo.split(":", 1)
...            return (urllib_parse.unquote(user), urllib_parse.unquote(pwd))
...        return urllib_parse.unquote(userinfo), None
...    return None, None

>>> username, password = parse_credentials(parsed.netloc)
>>> username, password
('someLogin', 'Password@')
```

Quoted:

```
>>> url = 'https://{}:{}@nexus.privatepypy.com/repository/pypi/xxx'.format(
...     urllib_parse.quote_plus('someLogin'), 
...     urllib_parse.quote_plus('Password@'), 
... )
>>> url
'https://someLogin:Password%40@nexus.privatepypy.com/repository/pypi/xxx'

>>> parsed = urllib_parse.urlparse(url)
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='someLogin:Password%40@nexus.privatepypy.com', path='/repository/pypi/xxx', params='', query='', fragment='')

>>> username, password = parse_credentials(parsed.netloc)
>>> username, password
('someLogin', 'Password@')
```

As you can see it *should* work in both cases. As I could confirm pip unquotes the username and password, so it is better to quote them.

If it still doens't work I would check the pip version or file a bug.

Comment: Now I get an error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ba633l99'
if my password is Ba633l99#!